# Lexicographical index of a combination

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have the following set $\{0,1,2,3\}$.

I generate all of the 4C2 subsets in lexicographical order.

$S_0 = \{0,1\}$

$S_1 = \{0,2\}$

$S_2 = \{0,3\}$

$S_3 = \{1,2\}$

$S_4 = \{1,3\}$

$S_5 = \{2,3\}$

Now I am attempting to get the index of the combination $\{0,3\}$. What I did was:

$3C2 + 0C1 = 3 + 0 = 3$ which does not equal $2$ for $S_2$.

I believe I am applying the combinatorial numbering system formula wrong?

I have looked at similar answers and they all seem to point to using the formula specified above.

Comment: There are $2^4 = 16$ subsets of the set $S = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ since each element in set $S$ can either be included or not included in a subset.  What you have done is counted the number of subsets with two elements.  Since you started your count of two-element subsets at $0$, the third such subset is $S_2$.

Comment: See  [combinadics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system).

Comment: @JMP this is the formula I believed I was using to try and get the number 2

Comment: @N.F.Taussig If I use the same formula to compute the lexographical index for {0,2} I get 2C2 + 0C1 = 1 . This corresponds to S_1 , so I'm confused as to why {0,3} does to give me S_2 . I believe it is somewhere in your comment, however I am at fault for not understanding

Comment: @N.F.Taussig also it does not seem to match up because 3C2 + 2C1 = 5 and not 6 for the sixth subset

Answer (score 1):

Write

$S_0=[1,0] => \binom{1}{2} + \binom{0}{1} = 0$

$S_1=[2,0] => \binom{2}{2} + \binom{0}{1} = 1$

$S_2=[2,1] => \binom{2}{2} + \binom{1}{1} = 2$

$S_3=[3,0] => \binom{3}{2} + \binom{0}{1} = 3$

$S_4=[3,1] => \binom{3}{2} + \binom{1}{1} = 4$

$S_5=[3,2] => \binom{3}{2} + \binom{2}{1} = 5$

instead.

Comment: How do I get the number corresponding to the lexographical order? So where (0,3) maps to 2 and (2,3) maps to 5

Comment: Also it seems that if we place the highest combination first, then (0,1) will have index 5. But this is not the number one gets when we do 1C1 + 0C0

Comment: @WeCanBeFriends; what do you get for the rest of them?

Comment: Deleted previous comment as I did not apply the formula correctly.

For (2,3) I do 3C2 + 2C1 = 5. This does not equal 0 either, but does equal S_5. For (1,3) I get 3C2 + 1C1 = 4. This equals S_4.

For (1,2) I do 2C2 + 1C1 = 2. This does not equal 3 as expected.

For (0,3) I do 3C2 + 0C1 = 3.

For (0,2) I do 2C2 + 0C1 = 1

For (0,1) I do 1C2 + 0C0 = 1

Comment: For (0,2) and (0,1) I get the same number which indicates that I have done something wrong. Can you see what it is?

Comment: @WeCanBeFriends; I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do it so the numbers run from 0 to n-1 instead?

Comment: I don't understand why (2,4) is 2C2 + 0C1 for example. I would have thought it would be 4C2 + 2C1... Can you explain?

Comment: Use the example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#National_Lottery_example_in_Excel

Comment: Map $0,\dots n-1$ to $1\dots n$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133872/discussion-between-wecanbefriends-and-jmp).